# vee-validate marks dirty because of vue composition API race condition

Tags: vuejs3

I have an app that has many nested components, surprise surprise.

Parent A - Calls Data, send to Parent B
Parent B - Creates form using Children
Child n - uses Vee-Validate's useField to create checkboxes

problem is when Parent B passes the data, {first: booleanVal, second: booleanVal, etc} it originally sends default of all false, but eventually sends the proper values. This is where the race condition comes into play, because of that initial send of all false, and then picks up the proper values it sees the form as dirty. I've set initialValue to props.modelValue thinking that would fix it as modelValue is kind of "keyword" of sorts. Everything looks right from a user's perspective, but if you try to leave the form it tells you to check one of the checkboxes (even though there are options checked). I've tried https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render to no avail.

If I on parent A do the v-if="!isLoading" so that Parent B doesn't load until the API is sent data back it removes the headache.